# Truncate HBase table with Java in Hadoop 2.7.1

Tags: hadoop, hbase, ambari

I'm trying to truncate HBase table with simple java code:

```
HBaseAdmin hbaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(new HadoopConfig());
```

but I get "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException".
I saw that that HBaseAdmin constructors are deprecated.

It works well with Hadoop 2.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Succeeded, Here is the solution:

```
    Admin admin = null;
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    // Add custom config parameters here

    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
    try {
        admin = connection.getAdmin();

        for (String tableName : tableNames) {
            System.out.print("Truncate table " + tableName);
            try {
                if (HBaseHelper.isTableExists(tableName)) {
                    if (admin.isTableDisabled(TableName.valueOf(tableName))) {
                        System.out.print("Table " + tableName + " was disabled. Enabling it...");
                        admin.enableTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName );
                    }
                    HBaseHelper.truncateTable(tableName);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.print("Failed to truncate table " + tableName + "\nError Msg: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print("Could not connect to HBase Admin. Error Msg: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the below code snippet to truncate HBase table in Java code,

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
// Add custom config parameters here
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
Admin admin = connection.getAdmin() 
admin.truncateTable(TableName.valueOf("bigtable");
admin.close();
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm not getting Invocation exception but "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotDisabledException".

Comment: I disabled the table before truncate and it succeeded. I will search for a way to do it without disabling it by myself.